# How to open chrome by default with Openbox (inside docker)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker, openbox

I have this docker image which streams my docker/ubuntu desktop to a browser using TurboVNC. That is all working fine (I'm using [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/commodustech/turbovnc-base) base image to do all that magic for me). This image uses Ubuntu and OpenBox. By default it starts an XTerm. In my case, however, I don't need an XTerm, but a browser (chrome) instead. Maybe I need more changes too (no context-menu, only allow google-chrome and maybe make the chrome window not closable if that is possible)

So, what I like to do, is to extends this base image and modify the Openbox configuration in my Dockerfile

```
FROM commodustech/turbovnc-base
# Install google-chrome (I can do this!)

# Configure OpenBox to open google-chrome by default
????
```

Any suggestion how to configure Openbox this way? Is there documentation I can use for this?

Comment: Do you want to build your own docker image (using `commodustech/turbovnc-base`  as the base image) which by running `docker run` runs Google chrome as default ? Because I think you could loggin into a shell session in the current docker container and install Google chrome and by using `docker exec ...` you run a custom script which runs Google chrome instead of xterm

Comment: Problem solved, they have added useful examples!

Comment: Glad you have solved! :)

Comment: You can self answer if you found it without help from here. It can help others.

Comment: Found an other image with good examples: https://hub.docker.com/r/commodustech/thaumatrope-base